# React Material-UI tabs with drawers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having an issue opening a drawer within the tab that is open using React and Material-UI. I am able to open the drawer but it shows in the first tab. At first I thought it was something wrong with the way I built my components, so I made a very simple one in WebpackBin and it does the same thing.

Has anyone been able to figure this out before? How can I make the drawer open inside the tab viewer? I am able to do it fine with dialogs but not with Tabs.

Here is a sample code

```
class sidebarDrawer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div>                
                 <p>My sidebar content</p>
             </div>
        );
    }
}

class TabComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           slideIndex: 0,
           open: false,
        };
    }

    handleChange = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            slideIndex: value,
        });
    };

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

    handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

    render() {
        let materialUITheme;
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
               <div>
                  <Tabs
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      value={this.state.slideIndex}>
                      <Tab label="Tab One" value={0} />
                      <Tab label="Tab Two" value={1} />
                  </Tabs>
                  <SwipeableViews
                      index={this.state.slideIndex}
                      onChangeIndex={this.handleChange}>
                      <div>
                          <h2 style={styles.headline}>Tabs with slide effect</h2>
                          Swipe to see the next slide.<br />
                      </div>
                      <div style={styles.slide}>
                          <div>
                              <RaisedButton
                                  label="Open Drawer"
                                  onClick={this.handleToggle}
                              />
                              <Drawer
                                  docked={false}
                                  width={200}
                                  open={this.state.open}
                                  onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
                              >
                                  <AppBar
                                      title="Playlists"
                                      onRightIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleClose}
                                      showMenuIconButton={false}/>
                                  <sidebarDrawer />
                              </Drawer>
                           </div>  
                       </div>
                   </SwipeableViews>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
         );
     }
}
```

Here is the [**WebpackBin**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KwkjpOcNF9BnwCrLaS-) for you to play with. Go to the second tab. Click the button. GO back to the first tab and you will see the drawer opened there.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be hackish way, but works

add style `position: 'relative'` to the tab

override position of `<Drawer>`

```
containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute' }}  // default is 'fixed'
overlayStyle={{ position: 'absolute' }}
```

working [**Webpack Bin**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kwkv2GkRPdyI-rdyPyz)

Comment: That's a good possibility. I'll get back to this once I test it out. Thank you

Comment: It works. I wish it wouldn't be css-based but the important thing is that it does the job, right?